# How do I disable Xcode C++ complier extensions?

Tags: c++, xcode

I am learning C++. I am using XCode IDE. I was requested to disable the C++ compiler extensions for doing my projects(homework). I have tried researching this, but I found no clear answers. Please help. Thank you.

I tried using the info found under this title, "disabling compiler extensions Xcode" that I found on Stackoverflow:

1.Select the project under which your target/executable belongs.

2.Select the target for which you want to provide the compiler flags.

3.Select "Build Phases" -> "compile sources"

4.Double click against the file which generates executable file.

5.Paste the compiler flag e.g. -fno-elide-constructors

That is it. Rebuild you target and you should not see any copy constructors getting ommitted."

Is this correct?
How can I tell if this is working?

Comment: The flags you want to set in order to disable compiler extensions are `-std=c++17 -pedantic-errors`. (Replace `17` with whatever version of the standard you are supposed to use if not the current C++17 one.)

Comment: Indeed; the term "extensions" refers to "GNU Extensions" which is enabled/disabled by setting the *C++ Language Dialect* in the Xcode project *Build Settings*.  They are enabled if you select `gnu++17` and disabled if you select `c++17`  See [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/350627/how-can-i-specify-the-c-version-to-use-with-xcode).

Comment: @trojanfoe, thank you for the responses. I think I understand now. The "GNU extensions" are additions to the C++ standard; is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: @trojanfoe, thank you. you rock!